# Interface methods with varying parameters

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface as such:

```
public interface ICompleteable 
{
    public void Complete();
}
```

However, I want to extend classes with methods as such, with varying parameters:

```
public class CompleteableClassA : ICompleteable 
{
    public void Complete(string name) { ... }
}

public class CompleteableClassB : ICompleteable
{
    public void Complete(string email, string password) { ... }
}
```

What is a good way (or even better, a pattern?) to go about extending methods from interfaces with varying parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a class that encapsulates the parameters, and extend that one if you want to:

```
public class CompleteParameters
{
  string parm1;
  // whatever you want
};

public class CompleteParametersTwo : CompleteParameters
{
  string parm2;
};


public interface ICompleteable 
{
    public void Complete(CompleteParameters parms);
}
```

Comment: Although I didn't precisely use this to solve the problem, this inspired the answer - to elaborate, I had many objects that I wanted to pass as parameters and found that they were easily (for the most part) encapsulated into a base class. I then passed a List<T> into the methods, where T is the type representing the base class I used.  Thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can not extend something that does not exist. So basically what you do here is just add new methods to every type, also those methods defer by definition from type to type, so there is no apparent common pattern that you may use in your interface.

You may think also about defining a base class, like :

```
public class Base {

   public void Complete(string name) { ... }
   public void Complete(string email, string password) { ... }
}
```

and after

```
public class CompleteableClassA : BaseClass, ICompleteable {
}

public class CompleteableClassB : BaseClass, ICompleteable {
}
```

In this case both classes share the same base class, so also share the same set of overloads of `Complete(..)` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use same type of parameters you can use `params`

```
interface ICompleteable
{
    void Complete(params string[] parameters);
}
```

or, for vary types you can use

```
interface ICompleteable
{
    void Complete(params object[] parameters);
}
```